# Can i write a file on application data directory[data/data/com.my.package/files/] from a system library present in system/lib/ in android?

Tags: android, c++, hal

I am designing a camera app which will be a system app. The app will be using a library[designed by us] present in system/lib/ in the HAL layer and we want to create a file inside data/data/com.my.package/files from the above said library from within HAL layer. Is it possible ? If so how ?

We are able to create a file inside /data/misc/ but not in the above path. Android OS version is 8.1 with HAL3. Appreciate the help.